# Change color on return data

Tags: powershell, output

I'm trying to modify a script that is supposed to list out all the computers within a domain, and if there is someone logged in on said computer it should show the username for the account.

The script works fine, but i got a little esthetic problem. Is there a way to turn the return data (for those computers and servers thats online) into another color?

Here is my current script:

```
function Check-Domain {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name |
        ForEach-Object {
            $computer = $_
            $pingme = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet -Count 1
            if ($pingme -eq $true) {
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
                    Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem |
                        Select-Object Username, Name }
            } else {
                Write-Host "$computer - OFF" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        } | Format-Table
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's easy enough. Just wrap the command up in a sub-expression and use `Write-Host` just like you do with the offline servers.

```
    {Write-Host $(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem | Select-Object username, name}) -ForegroundColor Green}
```

It'll execute the script inside the `$()` first, and then apply it's output to the `Write-Host` so that you can format it as desired. For output consistency, especially when it's just outputting text to the host, I personally like to use formatted strings. When used in combination with the `-NoNewLine` switch for `Write-Host` you can get some really sharp looking results.
[image]

Comment: Nice output on the screenie

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this part - this stores the result of `Invoke-Command` in a variable, and outputs it with the color you like with `Write-Host`:

```
if ($pingme -eq $true) {
    $result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
        Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username, Name
    }
    Write-Host $result -ForegroundColor Green
}
```